# User-Agents are removed by Chinese mobile networks?

Tags: mobile, localization, user-agent

Kindly confirm the information below.

a. Chinese mobile networks are blocking the useragent strings.

b. The user-agent send to the server are in different encoding for Chinese mobiles.

Please let me know whether a or b is true and also pour in your experiences on the identifying the user agents in Chinese mobiles.

Everywhere the term Chinese mobile means a mobile in China with Chinese mobile network.

Thanks in advance.

[changed]

Comment: How could (a) and (b) both be true?

Comment: This is the place to ask: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/wmlprogramming/

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this with my mobile phone. The user agent that is received by remote servers is both the same when I connect via WLAN and via GPRS (my SIM card is issued by China Mobile). There doesn't seem to be any filtering of user agents.

Specifically, my browser's user agent string is:

`Mozilla/5.0 (webOS/2.1.0; U; en-GB) AppleWebKit/532.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.0 Safari/532.2 Pre/1.1`

I'd say that neither *a* nor *b* is true.